# CMAKE shared library only creates the DLL and not the associated LIB

Tags: cmake

I am using CMAKE for configuring my project for Visual Studio and I have the following setup:

```
PROJECT(Proj1)
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.2.0)
# RPATH stuff - to avoid losing linking information
SET(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH FALSE)
SET(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH FALSE)
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib")
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)


# Variable for header and source files
SET(HEADERS
  api/mylib.h   
)
SET(SOURCES
  api/mylib.cpp
)

# Compile and link
ADD_LIBRARY(${NAME} SHARED ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${NAME} ${LIBS})
```

Now, this creates the project and I can compile it but it only produces the `Proj1.dll` file and not the associatwed `lib` file. I thought both the library and the shared object file should have been produced.

I am using `CMAKE 3.11.0` and `Visual Studio Community 2017`

Comment: Do you export any functions from this DLL with `__declspec(dllexport)`?

Comment: Ahhhhh....No, ok. This is something I have to look into. I never had to do that on Linux. Oh ok, so if nothing gets exported than the Archive will not be generated...

Comment: Then please have a look whether the `generate_export_header` function is suitable for you. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/module/GenerateExportHeader.html

Answer (score -8):

To create static library .lib, you have to use STATIC keyword instead of SHARED

```
ADD_LIBRARY(${NAME} STATIC ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES})
```

Take a look at:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_library.html

Comment: The question asks about SHARED libraries not static ones.

Comment: No. I am asking g about why the archive file is not created along with the DLL. As mentioned in the other comments, the function export directives need to be added on windows.

Comment: In case someone stumbles across this conversation, MSVC/Windows uses the same filename extension (.lib) for static libraries and export header, required to be able to link to DLLs. The presence of a .lib file is a compile-time requirement, while the presence of the .dll file is a run-time requirement.